# MVC4 Membership: How do I notify membership provider on logout?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, membership-provider, membership

I have cretated a very basic MVC 4 site using the VS2012 "Internet Application" template and I'm trying to implement a custom MembershipProvider class.

On login, the template code calls WebSecurity.Login(...) which ends up calling my providers ValidateUser method.

On logout, the template code calls WebSecurity.Logout() but as far as I can tell, this does not call any methods on my membership provider.

I need to find a way to notify my authentication back-end that the user logged out.

- Exactly what does WebSecurity.Logout do?
- How should I notify the membership provider that the user has logged out?

Answer (score 4):

> - Exactly what does WebSecurity.Logout do?

It calls the `SignOut` method on the `FormsAuthentication` class to remove the forms authentication cookie.

> - How should I notify the membership provider that the user has logged out?

It's not the responsibility of a membership provider to know whether a user has logged in or out. You should use the `[Authorize]` attribute on your controller actions or call the `User.IsInRole("someRole")` to test whether the current user is authenticated or not.

Comment: The authentication back-end needs to know if a session is live or not to keep track of who is logged in for license and messaging purposes. I had hoped to bundle all calls to the back end in the membership provider class but it looks like I need to make a direct call to the back-end API.